# ERROR 1060 (42S21) at line 3: Duplicate column name 'artkit0'

Tags: docker, azerothcore

trying to get Azerothcore running with Docker. I have the following error when trying to start up the service:

```
    >> Applying update "2022_06_14_01.sql" '90B07D9'...
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1060 (42S21) at line 3: Duplicate column name 'artkit0'

Applying of file '/azerothcore/data/sql/updates/db_world/2022_06_14_01.sql' to database 'acore_world' failed! If you are a user, please pull the latest revision from the repository. Also make sure you have not
applied any of the databases with your sql client. You cannot use auto-update system and import sql files from AzerothCore repository with your sql client. If you are a developer, please fix your sql query.
Could not update the World database, see log for details.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a total noob to this!

Answer (score 1):

I am receiving the same error. I have tried the various install types and made sure that things were cleaned up before trying again. I even went as far as to reformat and start from scratch. All yield the same as OP:

`ERROR 1060 (42S21) at line 3: Duplicate column name 'artkit0'`

I found a work around that worked for me. I dropped all the tables within acore_world and ran the server and let it repopulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest AzerothCore and try again